# Go back to the actual previous page regardless of a form post error

Tags: javascript

I have a page with a form. On this page there is also "go back to previous page" link, which uses the following JavaScript:

```
window.history.go(-1)
```

When the form is posted and there is a validation error, the website returns the user to the same form page. However, clicking on this link in case of a form validation error gets the user to the form page before its submission, not the actual, different previous page.

How can I get the user back to the actual previous page by ONLY using JavaScript? Please note that there could be multiple times of form submission with errors.

Comment: When you first land on the page, get the referring page. Store that somewhere. When the user wants to go back, go to the referrer.

Comment: How can I use a pure Javascript solution to get the complete URL of "the referring page" and store it somewhere? Considering the possibility of multiple form submission errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use [`location.replace()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp) in your redirect after validation error.

This will erase the current page location from the history and replace it with the new one, so it has no effect on page history.

---

Another option is to use [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) to check if the URL has actually changed after going back one page in the history.

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("back").onclick = function() {
    sessionStorage.setItem("href",location.href); //store current page into sessionStorage
    history.go(-1); //go back one page
  };
  if (location.href == sessionStorage.getItem("href")) {document.getElementById("back").click();} //if current page is the same as last one, go back one page
  else {sessionStorage.removeItem("href");} //clear sessionStorage
};
```

In the demos below (SO doesn't allow *sessionStorage*) I had to simulate both "going through the history", and "page load for every history item", so the code looks a little different, using an *array* and other *vars* and *functions*, but the principle should be the same:

**codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OgBgGg?editors=1011**
**jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j0ddnboq/2/**

Comment: No. I am using Java. Does this approach work with ONLY Javascript? Please note that there could be multiple form submission errors.

Comment: @curious1 Jep, this uses only JavaScript. What are you using for your form validation and redirect? Is that also only JavaScript? In that case, could you post a comment with the line that takes care of the redirect?

Comment: Form validation is done in the on the server. This is a Java website.

Comment: @curious1 Ah, thought maybe you were just mixing up the names. Better add a Java tag and maybe a line that validation is performed server-side using Java

Comment: @curious1 I added a solution using `sessionStorage`, only JavaScript and only client-side this time.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the "actual" previous page in a hidden form field on initial load and send this along with the form, then in your "go back to previous page" link js you could access that data.

Comment: How can I use a pure Javascript solution to get the complete URL of "the referring page" and store it somewhere on the form? Considering the possibility of multiple form submission errors?

Comment: @curious1 Another option would be to add a query parameter to the redirect with the number of 'backs', like: `?historyBack=3`. And then in JavaScript always check the [location.search](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp) for that parameter, and use that in your `window.history.go(-Math.abs(parseInt(historyBack)))` or something. I don't know if you have access to the validation/redirect script on the server.

Comment: @curious1 For that to work you'd obviously also have to send the current number of 'back' along with the form submission (retrieved from the [location.search](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp)), so it can be incremented.